# Display list content from other URL In HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to do a simple task; retrieve JSON using Jquery and display the name to a simple HTML list, usually, the JSON file I deal with is quite straightforward with a format of

> [ {a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}]

, but this time, the file (hosted on a different website) has a format similar to

> [
>   ["John",21,5,"description","some-link"],["Doe",3,6,"description","some-link"],]

with another 100k entries. My goal is to simply display all the names of this file in an HTML list.

Is there a way to retrieve the list and display content such as the name and description in simple HTML ul? 
the actual file link is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/104iutbz95o7wtw/test.json?dl=0 (consider it is actually hosted on a website for example: https://sample.com/test.json)

Comment: That's not valid json, so jQuery is probably firing off it's `fail` handler.

Comment: Also, if it's hosted on another website you may have a CORS problem.

Comment: Do you have a bigger example of your data?

Comment: @Adriano Hi, It pretty much follows the pattern I provided there, but the description has way too much content in it so it is hard for me to provide it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a regex to return a list of the data.

Have a look at this one I made for you: https://regex101.com/r/aDRp6A/1

It would help to know if the data has a strict structure or if it's variable.

**EDIT:**

Given your sample data I can see yours is just a list of lists. No curly brackets. That's good!
Once you have your json as a string try to split it:

```
myList = yourJsonObject;
```

And then you can access the data with:

```
myList[0][0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Im wondering if there is a way simliar to somthing like:for each item in List: name = item[0], number1=item[1] etc, also the actual file has been attached to the post, thanks again

Comment: Yes, I think I understand the steps needed, but due to my new exposure to Js, I have no idea how to retrieve the entire 2-D list from that web URL into my code, my current understanding of retrieving data from a different website is limited to .getJSON...

Comment: I got it using $.get() Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

hello you need to build your own parser or use regex, because the format that you mention is not JSON

Comment: Nothing wrong with the JSON shown with exceeption of a trailing comma which is probably a copy paste issue

Comment: what do you mean? json object format requires field (or key value) and apparently his data doesn't have them

Comment: @johnjerrico Yes I think the file format isnt JSON after all, but regardless, I still need to display the names of each objects in the HTML